# I'm unsubscribed from "Features & Announcements", why still receiving it? How to unsubscribe?

Tags: support, email

I just enter the unsubscribe url: https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/unsubscribe/1
and realized it's already "off" to "Features & Announcements", so why I did receive the last announcement?

Comment: What was the announcement that you received?

Comment: @NicolBolas I deleted it (even from trash), it was from may 5, I believe.

Comment: @NicolBolas stackoverflow for teams

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tom, I am the email marketing manager here at Stack Overflow. Just checked our email system and it shows that you were subscribed to the Features and Announcements list when the email about the Stack Overflow for Teams launch was sent to you May 9.

You clicked the unsubscribe link today and were unsubscribed from the Features and Announcement list.

The way that our unsubscribe link works is that when you click it, it automatically turns off the type of email that you just received. So it wasn't that you were already unsubscribed and you still received the email. It was that when you clicked unsubscribe, we automatically turned Features and Announcements off. We do that to keep you from having to take an extra step when you get to the Unsubscribe page.

@HansPassant - We don't want to send you emails that you don't want. If you visit our [Email Settings Page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current), you can choose the types of emails you do and don't want to receive. We don't believe in spam; if you are opted out of a specific type of email, you will no longer receive it.